# ContourPlot3D not producing any plots but no errors

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I cant get this code to work, although there are no errors. Any suggestions?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]';
G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
c = 299792458;
t0 = 1;
ContourPlot3D[
 t1 == t0/Sqrt[
    1 - ((2*G*
         M)/(r*(c)^2))], {M, ((6.5*10^9)*(1.989*10^30)), \
((6.5*10^9)*(1.989*10^32))}, {r, (2*10^15), (10^20)*2*10^43}, {t1, 0, 
  0.001}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe numbers are too high? Try to renormalize them like using units of solar masses and such...

Comment: This `With[{max=10^30},Plot3D[2*M/r,{M,0,max},{r,2*M,max}]]` works but fails for `max=10^40`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, it is not possible to renormalise this gravitational time dilation equation, because of G and c, the results are not right. You can renomalise when working with the algebra but you need to put the correct values of G and c in at the end. To get the correct results one has to use all values. The only way around it is to divide all numbers by say a million, but that does not work either.

Comment: @Betty Renormalization is surely possible for every physical equation ! What are the physical units of all the parameters?

Comment: In algebraic terms you can set G=c=1 but when computing exact values their magnitudes have to be included. Otherwise, I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simply that, it could not find anywhere where that

```
     1 == t0/Sqrt[    1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*(c)^2))]
```

is satisfied. You can see this using this trick

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]';
G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
c = 299792458;
t0 = 1;
eq = t1 == t0/Sqrt[1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*(c)^2))];
data = Reap@Monitor[ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@
      eq, {M, ((6.5*10^9)*(1.989*10^30)), 
((6.5*10^9)*(1.989*10^32))}, {r, (2*10^15), (10^20)*2*10^43}, {t1, 0, 
      0.001}], Sow@{eq, M, r, t1}];

data[[2]]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It gives `False` for each case. i.e. it could not find any values to satisfy the equation you gave.  It could be due to the large values you are using, or may be you are not using the correct ranges.

You get better result using `eq = t1 - t0/Sqrt[1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*(c)^2))]` instead, so you avoid the check for equality, Now it gives this:

```
data[[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the problem now. You `f[x,y,z]` which is `eq` here,  hardly changes  (it is the 4th element in each row). about `-0.999` But the scale of change in `M` and `r` coordinates is large.

The above is your data. Each row has `{M,r,t1,eq}` values. If you can scale down your physics data to small numbers, you might have better chance. But the data is there, you can see it in `data[[2]]` so you can try other commands on it to see if you can generate a plot from it. I did not try that.

You can clean `data[[2]]` as follows

```
data2 = data[[2]];
(First@data2)[[2 ;; -5]]
```

Which gives

```
{{7.72882*10^41, 1.75*10^63, 0.00040625, -0.999594}, {1.27285*10^42, 
  7.1875*10^62, 0.000234375, -0.999766}, {5.32897*10^41, 1.75*10^63, 
  0.00075, -0.99925}, {2.52914*10^41, 1.75*10^63, 
  0.0001875, -0.999812}, {4.729*10^41, 5.3125*10^62, 
  0.00025, -0.99975}, {1.09286*10^42, 2.5*10^62, 
  0.000249997, -0.99975}, {8.42878*10^41, 1.59375*10^63, 
  0.000249844, -0.99975}, {3.32909*10^41, 1.73437*10^63, 
  0.000249997, -0.99975}, {1.29286*10^40, 2.*10^63, 
  0.00025, -0.99975}, {7.32884*10^41, 1.79687*10^63, 
  0.000484375, -0.999516}, {1.13286*10^42, 2.5*10^62, 
  0.00025, -0.99975}, {2.12916*10^41, 1.5625*10^63, 
  0.0008125, -0.999188}, {2.32915*10^41, 1.35937*10^63, 
  0.000484375, -0.999516}, {4.32903*10^41, 2.03125*10^62, 
  0.000492188, -0.999508}, {8.12879*10^41, 2.65625*10^62, 
  0.0005, -0.9995}, {4.52902*10^41, 1.42857*10^56, 
  0.0005, -0.9995}, {2.92911*10^41, 1.51562*10^63, 
  0.000499997, -0.9995}, {1.29286*10^40, 2.*10^63, 
  0.0005, -0.9995}, {8.82875*10^41, 1.125*10^63, 
  0.000734375, -0.999266}, {7.32884*10^41, 7.5*10^62, 
  0.000875, -0.999125}, {4.02905*10^41, 1.76562*10^63, 
  0.000742187, -0.999258}, {4.92899*10^41, 1.5625*10^63, 
  0.000125, -0.999875}, {1.32921*10^41, 5.9375*10^62, 
  0.000734375, -0.999266}, {7.52883*10^41, 1.40625*10^62, 
  0.000749844, -0.99925}, {5.12898*10^41, 6.71875*10^62, 
  0.000749844, -0.99925}, {1.5292*10^41, 1.78125*10^63, 
  0.00075, -0.99925}}
```

You can now try other Mathematica plot functions. Basically, the above has the format `x,y,z,f(x,y,z)` for each row, where here `x` is `M` and `y` is `r` etc...

In Matrix form, it is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for that, but I do not understand why it fails at the higher numbers, for it should only fail at lower numbers. Also, it is weird that Mathematica will not plot for numbers where the equation is valid.

Answer (score 2):

- 

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]';
G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
c = 299792458;
t0 = 1;
equations = {t1 == t0/Sqrt[1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*c^2))], 
    6.5*10^9*1.989*10^30 <= M <= 6.5*10^9*1.989*10^32, 
    2*10^15 <= r <= 10^20*2*10^43, 0 <= t1 <= 0.001} // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Reduce[equations, {M, r, t1}]
FindInstance[equations, {M, r, t1}]
```

> `False`

> `{}`.

No solution here means that there no points satisfy the conditions.
`FindInstance` also indicate that we can't find any points here.

- Furthmore, the weaker conditions  `{M > 0, r > 0, 0 <= t1 <= 0.001}` still does not hold.

Comment: what about the condition {M > 0, r > 0, 0 <= t1 =>1}?

Comment: ClearAll["Global`*"]';
G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
c = 299792458;
t0 = 1;
equations = {t1 == t0/Sqrt[1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*c^2))], 
    6.5*10^9*1.989*10^30 <= M <= 6.5*10^9*1.989*10^32, 
    2*10^15 <= r <= 10^20*2*10^43, 0 <= t1 > 1} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Reduce[equations, {M, r, t1}]
FindInstance[equations, {M, r, t1}]

Comment: @Betty  `G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
c = 299792458;
t0 = 1;
equations = {t1 == t0/Sqrt[1 - ((2*G*M)/(r*c^2))], 
    6.5*10^9*1.989*10^30 <= M <= 6.5*10^9*1.989*10^32, 
    2*10^15 <= r <= 10^20*2*10^43, t1 >= 0} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Reduce[equations, {M, r, t1}]
FindInstance[equations, {M, r, t1}, 100] // N`